# Unable to make a pull in gradle file

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i´m trying to make a task in Gradle for my Android project ( using Kotlin DSL ) where I need to do an automatic pull for my "develop" branch.

This are the commnand I want to run :

```
git pull origin develop:develop
```

In the terminal this works just fine.

I`m using "commandLine" with "exec" in my gradle file and I´m having this error message:

code:

```
tasks.register<ReleaseTask>("makePull") {
    exec { commandLine("git", "pull", "origin develop:develop") }
}
```

error message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname origin develop: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I don´t have any issue if I try this commands in the terminal, do you know what i´m doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't separated the `origin` and the `develop:develop` arguments in the gradle version. Use this instead:

```
commandLine("git", "pull", "origin", "develop:develop")
```